# How to open the application on an iPad from a webpage?

Tags: ipad, html

We need to start an application on the iPad when the user clicks on a button in a web page. Please let us know the code snippets for the link to be added in the web page to open the application on the iPad. We are planning to create the web page using the ASP.net technology.

Answer (score 1):

This might be something you're looking for:
http://applookup.com/2010/09/iphone-apps-with-special-url-shortcuts/

**Updates**: the link above is dead. And as cdm9002 suggested, for the love of dogs, here are the information (credits goes to [iOS developer tips](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html))

First of all, you need to use method like UIApplication:openURL: to launch an application from a webpage. For example, you can launch Apple Mail in this way:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://info@iphonedevelopertips.com"]];
```

To launch your own application, there are two things to do: register the custom URL schemes and handle the URL launch in your application.

To register the custom URL schemes, you edit the info.plist. Below the custom scheme 'myapp' is registered.

```
CFBundleURLTypes 
    CFBundleURLSchemes 
      myapp 
    CFBundleURLName
    com.yourcompany.myapp
```

Now, you can launch the app with the following URLs.

```
myapp:// 
myapp://some/path/here 
myapp://?foo=1&amp;bar=2 
myapp://some/path/here?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

And in iPhone SDK (I think it applies to iPad as well), when launching the application in response to any of the URLs above, will send a message to the **UIApplicationDelegate**.

In order to retrieve the information passed in the URL, like /some/path/here, you simply provide an implementation for the message in your delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
  // Do something with the url here
}
```

Comment: I think the link you posted contains references that do answer the question, but can you include a summary of the important parts in your answer please?

Comment: This link is also now dead. For the love of dogs, please include the info rather than rely on external links working.